# EF6 + PostgreSQL + SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, entity-framework-6

I can't think of how to add a client certificate to the *EntityFramework6* database context.

When I create an *NPGSQL* connection myself, I can get what I want with *ProvideClientCertificatesCallback*. And it works.

```
...
                NpgsqlConnection conSql2 = new NpgsqlConnection();
                conSql2.ConnectionString = "<PGserver>;User Id=<UserName>;Password=<***>;Port=5432;Database=<DB>;SSL Mode=Require";
                conSql2.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += ProvideClientCertificatesCallback;
                conSql2.Open();
}
...
        static void ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(X509CertificateCollection clientCerts)
        {
            clientCerts.Add(new X509Certificate2(<UserName.pfx>, ""));
        }
...
```

And I don't understand how to use *ProvideClientCertificatesCallback* in the context of the database.

```
    ...
        public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
        {
            public AppIdentityDbContext() : base("name=DBcontext") {}
    
    
            static AppIdentityDbContext()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<AppIdentityDbContext>(new IdentityDbInit());
            }
    
            public static AppIdentityDbContext Create()
            {
                return new AppIdentityDbContext();
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
    
        }   // public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    ...
```

Accordingly, I get an error in the logs
**IMPORTANT: A valid client certificate is required to connect**
when calling

```
...
                using (AppIdentityDbContext appIdentDB = new AppIdentityDbContext())
                {
                    if (appIdentDB.Database.Exists()) blnIsExists = true;
...
```

My web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBcontext" connectionString="<PGserver>;User Id=<UserName>;Password=<***>;Port=5432;Database=<DB>;SSL Mode=Require"
    providerName="Npgsql"  />
</connectionStrings>


  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>


  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```